# Spring social /signin/facebook,/signin/linkedin,/signin/twitter gives 404 error

Tags: xml, facebook, spring, twitter, spring-social

Hy I integrated in my application spring social from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-sec. It works everithyng fine but I made a mistake, and becuase of it some things in my application did not work, but the login works, if I delete the second DispatcherServlet my site goes fine but social login gives 404 page not found. I know I don`t need 2 DispatcherServlet. This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>

<web-app id="MySite" version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name></display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/home</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>  
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-config.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.mysite.hrms.persistence.model.listeners.HRMSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!--    Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I think this:

```
<!-- Processes application requests -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value></param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

is overriding this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>  
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

This is my spring-config.xml:

```
<task:annotation-driven />


        <!-- Beans Definition -->
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">  
            <property name="driverClassName"    value="${database.driver}" />  
            <property name="url"                value="${database.url}" />  
            <property name="username"           value="${database.user}" />  
            <property name="password"           value="${database.password}" />  
        </bean>  

        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mysite.hrms"/>

            <property name="hibernateProperties">  
                <props>  
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>

                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>

                    <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">${hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults}</prop>

                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">${hibernate.connection.pool_size}</prop>
                </props>  
            </property>  
        </bean> 

        <bean id="txManager" 
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
            name="txManager">  
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean> 

        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver"/>

        <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/views/layout/config/layouts.xml</value>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/views/layout/config/views.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean> 

        <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" 
            class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />  

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
            <property name="prefix">  
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>  
            </property>  
            <property name="suffix">  
                <value>.jsp</value>  
            </property>  
        </bean>

        <bean id="messageSource"
            class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/messages" />
            <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
        </bean>

        <util:properties id="config" location="classpath:config/config.properties"/>

        <bean id="localeResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
            <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
        </bean>


        <!-- Context Configurations -->
        <context:annotation-config/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.mysite.hrms" />
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />


        <!-- Transaction Manager Configurations -->
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/> 


        <!-- MVC Configurations -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/event-photos/**" location="file:///${catalina.home}/data/events/"/>
        <mvc:resources mapping="/avatar/**" location="file:///${catalina.home}/data/avatar/"/>
        <mvc:interceptors>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
                </bean>
        </mvc:interceptors>

        <bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

        <bean id="mysiteUserDetailsService"
            class="com.mysite.hrms.persistence.service.impl.MySiteUserDetailsService">
        </bean>


        <bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
            class="com.mysite.hrms.handlers.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        </bean> 

        <bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" 
            class="com.mysite.hrms.handlers.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        </bean> 

        <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
            <property name="resourceLoaderPath">
                <value>/WEB-INF/templates/</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

and this is my springsocial config, social.xml:

```
<facebook:config app-id="xxxxxxxxx" app-secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" app-namespace="socialshowcase" />
    <twitter:config app-id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" app-secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <linkedin:config app-id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" app-secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>

    <social:jdbc-connection-repository/>    

    <bean id="userIdSource" class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource" />

    <bean id="connectController" class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController" autowire="constructor"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache" id="requestCache" />
    <bean id="psc" class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController" autowire="constructor" />        
    <bean id="signInAdapter" class="com.mysite.hrms.social.config.SimpleSignInAdapter" autowire="constructor" />
```

security.xml:

```
<beans:bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors"
        factory-method="noOpText" />
```

and my signInAdapter:

```
private final RequestCache requestCache;

    @Inject
    public SimpleSignInAdapter(RequestCache requestCache) {
        this.requestCache = requestCache;
    }

    @Override
    public String signIn(String localUserId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {
        SignInUtils.signin(localUserId);
        return extractOriginalUrl(request);
    }

    private String extractOriginalUrl(NativeWebRequest request) {
        HttpServletRequest nativeReq = request.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse nativeRes = request.getNativeResponse(HttpServletResponse.class);
        SavedRequest saved = requestCache.getRequest(nativeReq, nativeRes);
        if (saved == null) {
            return null;
        }
        requestCache.removeRequest(nativeReq, nativeRes);
        removeAutheticationAttributes(nativeReq.getSession(false));
        return saved.getRedirectUrl();
    }

    private void removeAutheticationAttributes(HttpSession session) {
        if (session == null) {
            return;
        }
        session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
    }
```

Probably something is missing from my spring social config. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I figgured out, I remove this /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml from my web.xml and I import the social.xml and secuirty.xml at the end of spring-config.xml and now again everithyng works fine. I think something was needed from my spring-config.xml and separated the program did not see.